# I keep getting and error Nameerror in my urls

Tags: python, django, url

Running Django 3.10
I keep getting

> NameError: name 'products_api_detail_view' is not defined

Urls

```
re_path(r'api/products/(?P<pk>\d+)/', products_api_detail_view),
```

views

```
def product_api_detail_view(request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = Products.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Products.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Not found"}) # return JSON with HTTP status code of 404
    return JsonResponse({"id": obj.id})
```

Comment: You did not import `products_api_detail_view`.

Answer (score 1):

You should import the view in your urls.py file
e.g from . import products_api_detail_view